# How stable is Orc.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: entity-framework-core, catel

I'm currently working on a WPF project with .NET 5.0 using Catel 5.12.19 and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.11.

For the EF part I use a code first approach.

When setting up everything using this [catel documentation](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CTL40/pages/36667396/Getting+started+with+Entity+Framework+in+Catel) I noticed the necessary extensions are moved to Orc.EntityFramework, but this supports EF 6 and up only.

For EF Core I find Orc.EntityFrameworkCore but only as Alpha versions.

I wondered how stable this is, anyone expercienes?

I'm specifically looking to the .IgnoreCatelProperties() extension

Jeroen

Comment: It's on our roadmap to migrate our existing apps that use Orc.EF to Orc.EFCore, but we haven't had the time to actually migrate it.

Comment: OK,  thanks,. Then I know that some parts of the old documentation can not yet be translated to the EF Core case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now it seems sufficient to add the following Ignores to the OnModelCreating

```
public class Model : DbContext
{

    public Model() : base() { }

    public Model(DbContextOptions<Model> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        new CustomersEntityTypeConfiguration()
            .Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Customers>()
            .Ignore("IsDirty")
            .Ignore("IsReadOnly")
            );
    }
    public DbSet<Customers> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class CustomersEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customers>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customers> builder)
        {
            builder                                    
                .Property(c => c.ID)                
                .IsRequired();
        }
    }
```